# Histograms in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-5.7, mariadb-10.5

We have several Linux based On-prem Mariadb 10.5.8 DB. Size is about 1 TB each.
Currently we don't have any script that does analyze table to gather statistics on our DB. It's done automatically based on the data. DB keeps growing. Wondering if I should add a cronjob to gather statistics once a month or so. I looked at Mariadb documentation and saw this command. Adding persistent for all, gathers column level statistics as well.

```
ANALYZE TABLE owner.tab1 persistent for all;
```

I tested this in lab, ran well. We have several tables that are really wide (too many unindexed columns). I am thinking about collecting column level stats as well using the above command. Does anyone have experience using it ? Did you find it useful ? What are some of the watch outs ?
Thanks
Moe

Comment: Index statistic is used by query execution plan builder. It allows to find the tables joining order and to define the indexes to be used for to make the query execution the most effective. If some query execution suddenly became slow then ANALYZE TABLE is needed to fresh the table statistic, in all other cases this service statement is obviously excess.

Comment: Histograms help in _some_ cases.  If you are having trouble with a particular query, let's discuss that query.

Answer (score 2):

Histograms can help the query optimizer to better estimate how many rows will pass a range condition (such as `a > 10 and a < 100` or `a in (1, 2, 5)`).
Histograms will be useful if the optimizer can not make use of an index to gather statistics for that particular column.

Histogram collection should be done whenever you think the data distribution in your columns has changed. That depends on how data is inserted into the database. For instance, batch loading of data might mean you add a completely new distribution to your data set, for example when you load census data for a country. That's probably very different than census data from other countries that may have been loaded. In that case you need to re-run analyze table after each batch insert if you want your histograms to be accurate.

If however you are running a web store and the pattern that customers usually have doesn't change, refreshing histograms won't improve the query planner's performance much.

As for gotchas:

1. Collection Performance

`ANALYZE TABLE ... PERSISTENT FOR ALL` can take a long time, especially for very big tables. This is because the histogram collection code takes note of every row in the table and that can end up spilling to a temporary file for storage which is much slower than memory.

There is a switch however to force histograms to be computed using only a fraction of the total table rows. [analyze_sample_percentage](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#analyze_sample_percentage)
This is set to 100 by default, but if you encounter performance problems, you can set it to 0, which will sample a percentage of rows appropriate for the data size (according to the [Jackknife Estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackknife_resampling)). You can also manually choose a percentage between 0 and 100 yourself. For very large datasets, a few percentage points should be enough.

2. Accuracy

MariaDB 10.0 -> 10.6 Histograms perform poorly with text data. They work well with numerical data, but sparse values do not provide good estimates. This is being fixed in MariaDB 10.7, with the addition of JSON format histograms and a different histogram computation algorithm. The details are a bit much for this post, but you can read more about it here:
https://mariadb.org/10-7-preview-feature-json-histograms/